Pasar por parametro de una función un elemento de un array
Tengo un array $purchase y a la hora de mostrar en un foreach sus valores en una tabla, necesito que uno de ellos, llame a una función a la que tengo que pasarle el id de purchase, pero me dice que no se puede convertir un array en cadena.
Esta es la línea en cuestión:
<td class="text-center"><?php echo total($purchase['id']); ?></td>´
El método es este:
function total($id){
        global $db;
        $sql="SELECT SUM(pd.total)";
        $sql.=" FROM purchase_details pd";
        $sql.=" INNER JOIN purchases p";
        $sql.=" ON pd.purchase_id=p.id";
        return find_by_sql($sql);
    }

Y este es el error que me muestra:

Warning: Array to string conversion in
C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\purchases.php on line 46 Array

He buscado por internet, pero no sé realmente cómo arreglarlo.

Al hacer:
<td class="text-center"><?php var_dump(total($purchase['id'])); ?></td>

Aparece lo siguiente:
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "18.50" ["SUM(pd.total)"]=> string(5) "18.50" } }


y cua es la linea 46??

si en la linea 46 hay una variable ... imprime su contenido con var_dump() a ver que tiene dentro ...

Pon todo el código, sin todo el código (o el que tiene errores) no podemos hacer mucho. Pon la función también. Me extraña, eres usuario viejo men.

<td class="text-center"><?php var_dump(total($purchase['id'])); ?></td>
Y aparece elo siguiente:                                                                                      array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "18.50" ["SUM(pd.total)"]=> string(5) "18.50" } }

Tienes razón, esta es la función: function total($id){   global $db;   $sql="SELECT SUM(pd.total)";   $sql.=" FROM purchase_details pd";   $sql.=" INNER JOIN purchases p";   $sql.=" ON pd.purchase_id=p.id";   return find_by_sql($sql);  }

Si, usuario viejo pero que no le entra el php por ningun poro de la piel

Mejor que rehagas tu pregunta o la edites, porque poner codigo en los comentarios ralla bastante y es dificil de ayudarte así.

Ya la tienes, he añadido la función. Mi duda es cómo tratar el array para poder extraer el id y pasarlo como parametro.

@CharlyUtrilla, viendo el código en tu comentario te puedo decir que para acceder a los datos tenés que hacer total($purchase['id'])[0][0]

viendo lo que has incluido en ningun momento seleccionas o recojes los ID de la base de datos, como pretendes que eso aparesca, no tiene nada que ver con PHP es un error en el query en donde no has agregado la logica para eso ...

Voy aventurarme en responderte aunque se que me van a tirar "hate" por esto.

Si, usuario viejo pero que no le entra el php por ningun poro de la piel

PHP es de los lenguajes más fáciles que existen, por eso algunos lo menosprecian. No es PHP, es tu lógica que parece que no la has desarrollado aun. Y para eso es otro enfoque.
Primero veamos como se trabaja un array
// Creo el array o lo obtengo de algún lado
$array = [
    'pedido'    => [
        'id' => '33',
        'datos' => [
            'producto' => 'PC Gammer',
            'total' => '5000',
        ],
    ],
];

/* 
Te lo he dicho miles de veces, debuggea siempre tu código.
Lo primero es siempre ver la estructura ORDENADA de un array
y eso lo haces dándole un formato más entendible al ser humano.
*/
// Imprimes en pantalla el array
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

// Resultado en pantalla del array
Array
(
    [pedido] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [datos] => Array
                (
                    [producto] => PC Gammer
                    [total] => 5000
                )

        )

)

/*
Una vez tienes la estructura, solo es de buscar de manera
lógica como poder acceder a un dato en concreto
*/

// Entro al array pedido y a al id
echo 'El ID es => <b>'.$id = $array['pedido']['id'].'</b>';
// Entro al array pedido, al otro array de datos y obtengo lo que quiero
echo '<br>El Producto <b>'.$array['pedido']['datos']['producto'].'</b> tiene un costo de <b>'.$array['pedido']['datos']['total'].'€</b>';

Resultado en HTML
El ID es => 33
El Producto PC Gammer tiene un costo de 5000€

Siguiente punto, esa función no te va a traer nada porque no le estas poniendo el ID para hacer la búsqueda. Veamos la query de una manera más sencilla.
/* Podrías ser desordenado y hacerlo así
 
function total($array['pedido']['id']){

Pero para mi, eso es de locos.
*/

// Yo prefiero crear variables para tener mejor el código
$id = $array['pedido']['id'];

function total($id){
   // Ahora la famosa query
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id_pedido = '$id' ";
   // Ejecutas tu query blablabla
}

Ahí si te creo que la función va a traer TODOS los daros de la tabla pedidos donde el ID sea igual al ID que le estas pasando por parámetro y que previamente has obtenido de quien sabe donde. Ahí si que te va a dar resultados la query.
Al final te falta lógica, pero como ya te lo he dicho antes, también te falta saber preguntar, porque si no preguntas bien (de hecho casi todas tus preguntas son confusas) no sabremos ayudarte de la mejor manera.
Un día de estos me contactas y te doy unas clasecitas de PHP 

Gracias por responder OCHOA, pero no me funciona. ¿Hay algun chat por el que podamos hablar y te enseño lo que he hecho? Mañana segurire dandole vueltas.

La verdad entrar al chat casi siempre termina en discusiones  explica mejor y listo.   Edita tu pregunta, y pon una línea divisoria, abajo de esa línea dime que es lo que tienes porque por millonésima vez NO SE ENTIENDE QUE RAYOS QUIERES  (en buena onda men)

Gracias a @Marcos logre que no me saliera ningun error. Además, he añadido un GROUP BY p.id para que no me doblara las cantidades totales.
